# ExtJs 6 Modern toolkit Multiselect field

Tags: javascript, multi-select, extjs6, extjs6-modern

I have upgraded my project from Sencha touch to extjs universal app , Most of the things are workng but no the MultiSelect field. It was working fine in sencha touch but not working in extjs 6 modern toolkit

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.field.Multiselect', {
extend: 'Ext.field.Select',
alias : 'widget.multiselectfield',

config: {
    delimiter: ',',

    mode: 'MULTI',

    doneButton: true
},
/**
 * Updates the {@link #doneButton} configuration. Will change it into a button when appropriate, or just update the text if needed.
 * @param {Object} config
 * @return {Object}
 */
applyDoneButton: function(config) {
    if (config) {
        if (Ext.isBoolean(config)) {
            config = {};
        }

        if (typeof config == "string") {
            config = {
                text: config
            };
        }

        Ext.applyIf(config, {
            text: 'Done',
            ui: 'action',
            height: '20px',
            margin: '5px auto 0px auto',
            width: '50%',
            docked: 'bottom',
            listeners: {
                tap: this.onButtonTap,
                scope: this
            }
        });
    }

    return Ext.factory(config, 'Ext.Button', this.getDoneButton());
},

/**
 * @private
 */
getTabletPicker: function() {
    var me = this,
        config = me.getDefaultTabletPickerConfig(),
        listMode = me.getMode();

    if (!me.listPanel) {
        me.listPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', Ext.apply({
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            modal: true,
            cls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'select-overlay',
            layout: 'fit',
            hideOnMaskTap: true,
            width: Ext.os.is.Phone ? '14em' : '18em',
            height: (Ext.os.is.BlackBerry && Ext.os.version.getMajor() === 10) ? '12em' : (Ext.os.is.Phone ? '12.5em' : '22em'),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'list',
                mode: listMode,
                store: me.getStore(),
                itemTpl: '<span class="x-list-label">{' + me.getDisplayField() + ':htmlEncode}</span>'
            }]
        }, config));

        if(listMode === 'SINGLE'){
            me.listPanel.down('list').on('itemtap',me.onListTap,me);
        }else{
            me.listPanel.add(this.getDoneButton());    
        }
    }
    return me.listPanel;
},
/**
 * @private
 */
onListTap : function(list,index,target,record) {
    this.setValue(record);
    this.callParent();
},
/**
 * @private
 */
onButtonTap: function(){
    var records = this.listPanel.down('list').getSelection();
    this.setValue(records);
    this.superclass.onListTap.call(this);
},
/**
 * @private
 */
applyValue: function(value) {
    this.getOptions();
    return  this.getValueFromRecords(value,this.getValueField());
},
/**
 * @private
 */
updateValue: function(newValue, oldValue) {
    var me = this,
        value = me.convertValue(newValue,me.getValueField(),me.getDisplayField());

  value = value.join(me.getDelimiter());
  me.superclass.superclass.updateValue.call(me,[value]);
},
/**
 * @private
 */
convertValue: function(value,fieldIn,fieldOut){
    var delimiter = this.getDelimiter(),
        store = this.getStore(),
        i = 0,
        out = [],
        len,
        item;

    if (value) {
        if (delimiter && Ext.isString(value)) {
            value = value.split(delimiter);
        } else if (!Ext.isArray(value)) {
            value = [value];
        }

        for (len = value.length; i < len; ++i) {
            item = store.findRecord(fieldIn,value[i]);
            if(item)
                out.push(item.get(fieldOut));
        }
    }
    return out;
},
/**
 * @private
 * Returns the value in array form from records
 */
getValueFromRecords: function(value){
    var delimiter = this.getDelimiter(),
        valueField = this.getValueField(),
        i = 0,
        out = [],
        len,
        item;

    if (value) {
        if (delimiter && Ext.isString(value)) {
            value = value.split(delimiter);
        } else if (!Ext.isArray(value)) {
            value = [value];
        }

        for (len = value.length; i < len; ++i) {
            item = value[i];
            if (item && item.isModel) {
                out.push(item.get(valueField));
            }
        }
        out = Ext.Array.unique(out);
    }
    return out.length > 0 ? out : value;
},
/**
 * @private
 */
getRecordsFromValue: function(value){
    var records = [],
        all = this.getStore().getRange(),
        valueField = this.getValueField(),
        i = 0,
        allLen = all.length,
        rec,
        j,
        valueLen;

    if(value){
        for (valueLen = value.length; i < valueLen; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < allLen; ++j) {
                rec = all[j];   
                if (rec.get(valueField) == value[i]) {
                    records.push(rec);
                    break;
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    return records;
},
/**
 * Returns the current selected {@link Ext.data.Model records} instances selected in this field.
 * @return {Ext.data.Model[]} An array of Records.
 */
getSelection: function() {
    return this.listPanel.down('list').getSelection();
},
/**
 * Returns the current selected records as an array of their valueFields.
 * @return {Array} An array of valueFields
 */
getValue: function() {
    return this._value;
},
/**
 * @private
 */
onChange: function(component, newValue, oldValue) {
    var me = this,
        old = me.convertValue(oldValue,me.getDisplayField(),me.getValueField());

    me.fireEvent('change', me, me.getValue(), old);
},
/**
 * Shows the picker for the select field, whether that is a {@link Ext.picker.Picker} or a simple
 * {@link Ext.List list}.
 */
showPicker: function() {
    var me = this,
        store = this.getStore();

    //check if the store is empty, if it is, return
    if (!store || store.getCount() === 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (me.getReadOnly()) {
        return;
    }

    me.isFocused = true;

    var listPanel = me.getTabletPicker(),
        list = listPanel.down('list'),
        index, records,
        value = me.getValue();

    if (!listPanel.getParent()) {
        Ext.Viewport.add(listPanel);
    }

    if(value){
        records = me.getRecordsFromValue(value);
        list.select(records, null, true);
    }else{
        list.deselectAll();
    }

    listPanel.showBy(me.getComponent(), (Ext.os.is.BlackBerry && Ext.os.version.getMajor() === 10) ? 't-b' : null);
},
/**
 * Called when the internal {@link #store}'s data has changed.
 */
onStoreDataChanged: function(store) {
    var me = this,
        initialConfig = me.getInitialConfig(),
        value = me.getValue();

    if (value || value === 0) {
        me.updateValue(me.applyValue(value));
    }

    if (me.getValue() === null) {
        if (initialConfig.hasOwnProperty('value')) {
            me.setValue(initialConfig.value);
        }

        if (me.getValue() === null && me.getAutoSelect()) {
            if (store.getCount() > 0) {
                //me.setValue(store.getAt(0));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

});

when i click on done it doesn't hide the list and doesn't add the multiple values to the inut field

the error in console

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you done any basic debugging? What are the errors?

Comment: What code do you have in `superclass.onListTap()`. Nobody can help you if you do not show your code.

Comment: Well if you are not Extjs developer you won't understand, But i extends it from Select field so it contains the superclass of Ext.field.Select

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for mutliselect in Extjs 6 modern toolkit

create a file inside *`ext\modern\modern\src\ux\field`*, named `MutliSelect.js`
and copy the following code to it

```
Ext.define('Ext.ux.field.Multiselect', {
extend: 'Ext.field.Select',
alias : 'widget.multiselectfield',

require:['Ext.field.Select'],
config: {
    delimiter: ',',

    mode: 'MULTI',

    doneButton: true
},
/**
 * Updates the {@link #doneButton} configuration. Will change it into a button when appropriate, or just update the text if needed.
 * @param {Object} config
 * @return {Object}
 */
applyDoneButton: function(config) {
    if (config) {
        if (Ext.isBoolean(config)) {
            config = {};
        }

        if (typeof config == "string") {
            config = {
                text: config
            };
        }

        Ext.applyIf(config, {
            text: 'Done',
            ui: 'action',
            height: '20px',
            margin: '5px auto 0px auto',
            width: '50%',
            docked: 'bottom',
            listeners: {
                tap: this.onButtonTap,
                scope: this
            }
        });
    }

    return Ext.factory(config, 'Ext.Button', this.getDoneButton());
},

/**
 * @private
 */
getTabletPicker: function() {
    var me = this,
        config = me.getDefaultTabletPickerConfig(),
        listMode = me.getMode();

    if (!me.listPanel) {
        me.listPanel = Ext.create('Ext.Panel', Ext.apply({
            left: 0,
            top: 0,
            modal: true,
            cls: Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'select-overlay',
            layout: 'fit',
            hideOnMaskTap: true,
            width: Ext.os.is.Phone ? '14em' : '18em',
            height: (Ext.os.is.BlackBerry && Ext.os.version.getMajor() === 10) ? '12em' : (Ext.os.is.Phone ? '12.5em' : '22em'),
            items: [{
                xtype: 'list',
                mode: listMode,
                store: me.getStore(),
                itemTpl: '<span class="x-list-label">{' + me.getDisplayField() + ':htmlEncode}</span>'
            }]
        }, config));

        if(listMode === 'SINGLE'){
            me.listPanel.down('list').on('itemtap',me.onListTap,me);
        }else{
            me.listPanel.add(this.getDoneButton());    
        }
    }
    return me.listPanel;
},
/**
 * @private
 */
onListTap : function(list,index,target,record) {
    this.setValue(record);
    this.callParent();
},
/**
 * @private
 */
onButtonTap: function(){
    var records = this.listPanel.down('list');
    this.setValue(records.selected.keys);
    this.updateValue(records.selected.keys, this.getValue());
    this.listPanel.hide();
},
/**
 * @private
 */
applyValue: function(value) {
    this.getOptions();
    return  this.getValueFromRecords(value,this.getValueField());
},
/**
 * @private
 */
updateValue: function(newValue, oldValue) {
    var me = this,
        value = me.convertValue(newValue,me.getValueField(),me.getDisplayField());

  value = value.join(me.getDelimiter());
  me.superclass.superclass.updateValue.call(me,[value]);
},
/**
 * @private
 */
convertValue: function(value,fieldIn,fieldOut){
    var delimiter = this.getDelimiter(),
        store = this.getStore(),
        i = 0,
        out = [],
        len,
        item;

    if (value) {
        if (delimiter && Ext.isString(value)) {
            value = value.split(delimiter);
        } else if (!Ext.isArray(value)) {
            value = [value];
        }

        for (len = value.length; i < len; ++i) {
            item = store.findRecord(fieldIn,value[i]);
            if(item)
                out.push(item.get(fieldOut));
        }
    }
    return out;
},
/**
 * @private
 * Returns the value in array form from records
 */
getValueFromRecords: function(value){
    var delimiter = this.getDelimiter(),
        valueField = this.getValueField(),
        i = 0,
        out = [],
        len,
        item;

    if (value) {
        if (delimiter && Ext.isString(value)) {
            value = value.split(delimiter);
        } else if (!Ext.isArray(value)) {
            value = [value];
        }

        for (len = value.length; i < len; ++i) {
            item = value[i];
            if (item && item.isModel) {
                out.push(item.get(valueField));
            }
        }
        out = Ext.Array.unique(out);
    }
    return out.length > 0 ? out : value;
},
/**
 * @private
 */
getRecordsFromValue: function(value){
    var records = [],
        all = this.getStore().getRange(),
        valueField = this.getValueField(),
        i = 0,
        allLen = all.length,
        rec,
        j,
        valueLen;

    if(value){
        for (valueLen = value.length; i < valueLen; ++i) {
            for (j = 0; j < allLen; ++j) {
                rec = all[j];   
                if (rec.get(valueField) == value[i]) {
                    records.push(rec);
                    break;
                }
            }   
        }
    }
    return records;
},
/**
 * Returns the current selected {@link Ext.data.Model records} instances selected in this field.
 * @return {Ext.data.Model[]} An array of Records.
 */
getSelection: function() {
    return this.listPanel.down('list').getSelection();
},
/**
 * Returns the current selected records as an array of their valueFields.
 * @return {Array} An array of valueFields
 */
getValue: function() {
    return this._value;
},
/**
 * @private
 */
onChange: function(component, newValue, oldValue) {
    var me = this,
        old = me.convertValue(oldValue,me.getDisplayField(),me.getValueField());

    me.fireEvent('change', me, me.getValue(), old);
},
/**
 * Shows the picker for the select field, whether that is a {@link Ext.picker.Picker} or a simple
 * {@link Ext.List list}.
 */
showPicker: function() {
    var me = this,
        store = this.getStore();

    //check if the store is empty, if it is, return
    if (!store || store.getCount() === 0) {
        return;
    }

    if (me.getReadOnly()) {
        return;
    }

    me.isFocused = true;

    var listPanel = me.getTabletPicker(),
        list = listPanel.down('list'),
        index, records,
        value = me.getValue();

    if (!listPanel.getParent()) {
        Ext.Viewport.add(listPanel);
    }

    if(value){
        records = me.getRecordsFromValue(value);
        list.select(records, null, true);
    }else{
        list.deselectAll();
    }

    listPanel.showBy(me.getComponent(), (Ext.os.is.BlackBerry && Ext.os.version.getMajor() === 10) ? 't-b' : null);
},
/**
 * Called when the internal {@link #store}'s data has changed.
 */
onStoreDataChanged: function(store) {
    var me = this,
        initialConfig = me.getInitialConfig(),
        value = me.getValue();

    if (value || value === 0) {
        me.updateValue(me.applyValue(value));
    }

    if (me.getValue() === null) {
        if (initialConfig.hasOwnProperty('value')) {
            me.setValue(initialConfig.value);
        }

        if (me.getValue() === null && me.getAutoSelect()) {
            if (store.getCount() > 0) {
                //me.setValue(store.getAt(0));
            }
        }
    }
}

});
```

and than use the `xtype` as `multiselectfield`,

Comment: Error this line `return this.listPanel.down('list').getSelection();` Extjs 6.6